# How to create a spatial value heat map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I recently started using R and came upon a data set (`sample`) with geographical data. It contains longitude, latitude and a fill-variable called Tdiff. I want to plot a heat map that represents the value of Tdiff and NOT the simple count of points.

I am using `ggplot` and ended up using the following code. It will show me the right legend, but it shows a bare plot.

```
ggplot(data = sample, aes(x = lon, y =lat)) + 
  geom_hex(aes(fill = Tdiff), stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('lightblue', 'yellow', 'red')) +
  xlab(label = 'longitude') +
  ylab(label = 'latitute') +
  coord_equal()
```

I figured out that if I leave out the `stat` argument the hexagons will be shown in the plot, but they are not filled with the gradient.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Here is a `str` output of my data and a link to the dataset in dropbox:

```
str(sample)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ lon  : num  -90.3 -90.3 -90.3 -90.3 -90.3 ...
 $ lat  : num  -1.39 -1.41 -1.42 -1.43 -1.43 ...
 $ Tdiff: int  0 1341 457 426 335 1 395 122 335 975 ...
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ce6gju5ill8ncif/sample.txt?dl=0

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your data is a bit odd since contains values for few combinations of lon and lat.

Comment: Yes, try plotting your data with `geom_point()` and think about what you actually want to do with this data. Are you sure `geom_hex()` makes sense given the data is so sparsely spread across the `lat` and `lon`?

Comment: And what do you want to be shown if there are multiple observations in one hex-field? The sum of `Tdiff`? I agree with Marius, you'd probably better use geom_point() here

Comment: The data I put on dropbox is only a sample of the original data set.I thought like this it would be easier, since the originial data set is quite big. And yes if there are many observations for one field I would like to plot the sum of Tdiff. This sum may be 0 if there are no points in one field. I tried `stat_bin_hex before`, but the problem is that the code would only use count of plotted points and not the sums of `Tdiff` as value for the hex-fields. Sorry for not making that clear in the beginning.

Comment: For all who want to use a larger data set here is another link to larger sample. This should look more exciting. https://www.dropbox.com/s/cud5fy1s6als48h/sample2.txt?dl=0